# How do I tell ReactiveUI to update bindings (i.e. RaiseCanExecuteChanged())?

Tags: reactiveui

How do I tell ReactiveUI to update bindings?

Normally, I would do something like this:

```
    string _instructorNameInput;
    public string InstructorNameInput
    {
        get { return _instructorNameInput; }
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _instructorNameInput, value);
            Submit.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```

However, the following isn't supported:

```
Submit.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

As a result, how can I force bindings to update based on the CanExecute predicate that my command relies on?

**Updated:**

```
public partial class FormViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public FormViewModel()
    {
        Submit = ReactiveCommand.Create(this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.CanSubmit));
        Submit.Subscribe(x => OnSubmit());
    }

    bool _canExecute;
    public bool CanSubmit
    {
        get { return !GetUnsatisfied().Any(); }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _canExecute, value); } // Need to update view based on command.CanExecute state change
    }
    void OnSubmit()
    {
        var rosterInfo = new RosterInfo(new Course(CourseInput.Name),
                                        new Instructor(InstructorNameInput, InstructorIdInput));
        var repository = GetRepository();
        repository.AddCourseInfo(rosterInfo);

        Publish(REQUEST_NAVIGATION_TO_SUBMITION_CONFIRMATION, rosterInfo);
    }

    ObservableCollection<RequiredField> GetUnsatisfied()
    {
        RequiredFields.Clear();
        RequiredFields = Review();
        return RequiredFields;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Submit`? Is it a ReactiveCommand?

Comment: Yes. It's a ReactiveCommand.

Comment: It is really unclear what is your problem. Could you please provide a complete view model code (with constructor, command, and property), and state clearly what behaviour you want to achieve, and what behaviour you observe in your program?

Comment: I updated the code example. I need my CanExecute to trigger a refresh on my view. DelegateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChange() does this for me in Prism. However, I do not know how to do this using ReactiveUI.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple issues:

Have a read at the [fundamentals](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-models/) on `ReactiveObject`, in particular how "Read-Write Properties" are written.

In your case, `this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.CanSubmit)` will trigger a refresh on the command whenever the property `CanSubmit` changes, but this one never does, because you never call the setter (and the getter has an incorrect impl).

Currently, your method `GetUnsatisfied()` has "polling" semantics, which mean you need something to trigger this method to update your command. This isn't reactive at all, you should instead bind/listen to updates.

If there's no way for you to make your `Review()` logic reactive, then you may do something like:

```
var canExec = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                        .Select(_ => !GetUnsatisfied().Any());
Submit = ReactiveCommand.Create(canExec);
Submit.Subscribe(x => OnSubmit());
```

Basically, having a timer to do your polling.
(But I strongly suggest going further down the reactive way)